# Looping through table using selenium (c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem of filling in this dictionary with a result from HTML table.
HTML looks something like this:

```
  <td class="name">
     <span data-bind="text:'hierarchyId'"></span>
     <span data-bind="text:'name'"></span> 
   </td>
```

I want to fill in dictionary with HiearchyId and name for every td, but it ends up filling only first column and in second iteration return error that same ID already exist in dictionary.
Please advice.

```
  public Dictionary<string,string> ListOfSections()
    {
        Dictionary<string,string> newDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        IList<IWebElement> tdSectionName = sectionTable.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@class='name']"));
        foreach (IWebElement element in tdSectionName)
        {
            IWebElement hierarchy = element.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@data-bind='text: hierarchyId']"));
            IWebElement name = element.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@data-bind='text: Name']"));
            newDictionary.Add(hierarchy.Text, name.Text);
        }
        return newDictionary;
    }
```

Comment: `foreach (IWebElement element in tdName)` should you use `tdSectionName` list? I don't know from where you are getting the `tdName`.

Comment: can you also make sure the html is correct, we don't see the `data-bind` attribute for the span.

Comment: you are right. I am using tdSectionName acutally but edited the code before upload.  Html is not complete. I just wanted to point that there are two span inside one td element so I sketched the html. But yes there is data-bind attribute in the html.Ty for you comment

Answer (score 2):

Add `.//` to xpath to get child element like below, or use css selector:

```
public Dictionary<string,string> ListOfSections()
{
    Dictionary<string,string> newDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    IList<IWebElement> tdSectionName = sectionTable.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@class='name']"));
    foreach (IWebElement element in tdName)
    {
        IWebElement hierarchy = element.FindElement(By.XPath(".//span[@data-bind='text: hierarchyId']"));
        IWebElement name = element.FindElement(By.XPath(".//span[@data-bind='text: Name']"));
        newDictionary.Add(hierarchy.Text, name.Text);
    }
    return newDictionary;
}
```

Css selector:

```
public Dictionary<string,string> ListOfSections()
{
    Dictionary<string,string> newDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    IList<IWebElement> tdSectionName = sectionTable.FindElements(By.CssSelector("td.name"));
    foreach (IWebElement element in tdName)
    {
        IWebElement hierarchy = element.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[data-bind='text: hierarchyId']"));
        IWebElement name = element.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[data-bind='text: Name']"));
        newDictionary.Add(hierarchy.Text, name.Text);
    }
    return newDictionary;
}
```

Comment: An needs to check if hierarchy and name is not null!. is it true?

Comment: Explain, what do you mean null?

Comment: It is possible that parent element has no span[data-bind='text: hierarchyId'] or span[data-bind='text: Name'] child?

Comment: @isaeid you should know it. If not found you'll get an error

Comment: @runningman you can use `element.FindElements(By.CssSelector("span[data-bind='text: hierarchyId']"))` and check size. If >0 than element exit.